# Spark, why does adding an 'or' clause inside a join creates a cartesian product plan

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the two following dataframes:

```
df1: 
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  2|  5|
|  2|  6|
|  3|  7|
|  3|  8|
+---+---+

info:
+---+---+------------+
|  a|  b|           i|
+---+---+------------+
|  1|  2|1 --> 2 info|
|  1|  3|1 --> 3 info|
|  7|  3|3 --> 7 info|
+---+---+------------+
```

For each row in 'df1' I want to find a corresponding row in 'info':

```
select df1.*, info.i from df1
join info 
  on 
    (df1.a = info.a and df1.b = info.b)
```

This works and generates the following explain plan:

```
*(5) Project [a#0L, b#1L, i#6]
+- *(5) SortMergeJoin [a#0L, b#1L], [a#4L, b#5L], Inner
   :- *(2) Sort [a#0L ASC NULLS FIRST, b#1L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#0L, b#1L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#37]
   :     +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(a#0L) AND isnotnull(b#1L))
   :        +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]
   +- *(4) Sort [a#4L ASC NULLS FIRST, b#5L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#4L, b#5L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#43]
         +- *(3) Filter (isnotnull(a#4L) AND isnotnull(b#5L))
            +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[a#4L,b#5L,i#6]
```

However, looking at the output:

```
+---+---+------------+
|  a|  b|           i|
+---+---+------------+
|  1|  3|1 --> 3 info|
|  1|  2|1 --> 2 info|
+---+---+------------+
```

I understand this is not good enough for me. 'info' table has no meaning to order. So I want the record a=3, b=7 in df1 to be paired with the record a=7, b=3 in info.

```
select df1.*, info.i from df1
join info 
  on 
    (df1.a = info.a and df1.b = info.b) or 
    (df1.a = info.b and df1.b = info.a)
```

Output is exactly as I wanted:

```
+---+---+------------+
|  a|  b|           i|
+---+---+------------+
|  1|  2|1 --> 2 info|
|  1|  3|1 --> 3 info|
|  3|  7|3 --> 7 info|
+---+---+------------+
```

However, the explain plan worries me:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [a#0L, b#1L, i#6]
+- CartesianProduct (((a#0L = a#4L) AND (b#1L = b#5L)) OR ((a#0L = b#5L) AND (b#1L = a#4L)))
   :- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]
   +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[a#4L,b#5L,i#6]
```

Questions:

1. Is adding the OR clause correct? We can assume 'df1' and 'info' tables are unique in (a,b). df1 is ordered but info is not.
2. why did the plan change?

I am running on Spark 3.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adding an `OR` condition to a join clause makes it impossible to easily ensure that rows to be joined are regrouped on the same executor and can be effectively matched within the same executor. Thus in this case Spark is forced to use the naive cartesian product algorithm to join dataframes**

To simplify, let's look at the first step of Spark join algorithm: regrouping the rows that will be matched together to the same executor. The second step (efficiently join rows within the same executor) is a bit more complicated but have the same issue with `OR` condition.

Spark regroups rows of a dataframe to executors (repartition) by using an hash function on join columns of dataframe, and send rows with similar hashes to same executor (for instance, similar hashes can be hashes starting with the same characters)

#### Example

Let's take two dataframe to join, `df1` and `df2`. Here is `df1`:

| row | k1 | k2 | v1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | X1 |
| 2 | 1 | B | X2 |
| 3 | 2 | A | X3 |
| 4 | 2 | B | X4 |

And here is `df2`:

| row | k1 | k2 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | A | Y1 |
| 6 | 1 | B | Y2 |
| 7 | 2 | A | Y3 |
| 8 | 2 | B | Y4 |

We will join those two dataframes on a Spark cluster with 2 executors

#### AND join condition

We use `df1.k1 = df2.k1 AND df1.k2 = df2.k2` for join condition

If we use concatenation of `k1` and `k2` (very bad hash function, by the way) as an hash function and use the first character to regroup, the first two rows of `df1` will be matched with the first two rows of `df2` and the last two rows of `df1` will be matched with the first two rows of `df2`.

So you can split your two dataframes, putting the first two rows on one executor and last two rows on the other executor and then perform the join independently on each executor.

#### OR join condition

However, if we change join condition to an `OR` condition, `df1.k1 = df2.k1 OR df1.k2 = df2.k2`

In this case, hashing doesn't work anymore, as row 1 of `df1` will be matched to row 5, 6 and 7 of `df2` and row 2 of `df1` will be matched to row 5, 6 and 8 of `df2`. So the first two rows of `df1` will be matched to all rows of `df2`. And the first two rows of `df2` will be matched to all rows of `df1`.

So you can't split your dataframes to send on executors parts that can be treated independently anymore.

#### Conclusion

As we can see, for `OR` condition, you can't use hash to distribute rows for a join. So, when Spark see an `OR` condition on a join, it can't select hash based join algorithms. For a similar reason, it can't select *Sort Merge Join* algorithm.

So two algorithms remains available for Spark to chose: *Broadcast Nested Loop Join* and *Cartesian Product*. If one of the dataframe is small, Spark will use *Broadcast Nested Loop Join*. Else Spark will use *Cartesian Product*

That's why adding an `OR` condition makes Spark use a Cartesian Product plan.

Comment: Wow! This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for this great explanation Vincent.

Comment: One question though: in my example, the or clause is b/w tow expressions both referring to the same records so in theory concatenating the values and hashing them shoild work. But I guess it is too specific a case for the optimizer to handle right?

Answer (score 2):

Max and min can be evaluated and used for join (Scala):

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 4),
  (2, 5),
  (2, 6),
  (3, 7),
  (3, 8)
).toDF("a", "b")
  .withColumn("maxValue", when($"a">$"b", $"a").otherwise($"b"))
  .withColumn("minValue", when($"a">$"b", $"b").otherwise($"a"))


val info = Seq(
  (1, 2, "1 --> 2 info"),
  (1, 3, "1 --> 3 info"),
  (7, 3, "3 --> 7 info")
).toDF("a", "b", "i")
  .withColumn("maxValue", when($"a">$"b", $"a").otherwise($"b"))
  .withColumn("minValue", when($"a">$"b", $"b").otherwise($"a"))


df1
  .join(info, Seq("maxValue", "minValue"))
  // drop unused columns
  .drop("maxValue", "minValue")
  .drop(info.col("a")).drop(info.col("b"))
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------------+
|a  |b  |i           |
+---+---+------------+
|1  |2  |1 --> 2 info|
|1  |3  |1 --> 3 info|
|3  |7  |3 --> 7 info|
+---+---+------------+
```

Comment: Interesting!
I actually thought about creating a key in each table whereby I concat the values but sort them first (I guess this is equivalent to your suggestion). However- why does simply adding an 'OR' clause not a good idea?

Comment: Yes :-) 
Do you know why is this so in this case?

Comment: Joining dataframes by "Or" have poor performance usually; "Or" is working fine in filtering records inside one dataframe.

Comment: I am reassigning the 'accepted answer' to Vincent as he accurately answered my original question. You still have my upvote and thanks though.